# nhibernate - Incorrect generated SQL when running count w/ a join

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hql

All,

I am using Nhibernate 3.3, asp.net 2.0.

The HQL below is incorrectly translated to the SQL ONLY when I run the count query, in other words, I run 2 queries:

1) First query to query result

2) Same query but change the select columns, to select count(*)

It appears my joins are gone but I need them for filtering!
Do you think the 'fetch' keyword is screwing things up? I technically don't need "fetch" in the query when I am doing count() but need it for the first query.

HQL before running it:

```
                                 select count(legal.id) from OtherRPlan_ p
                                    inner join fetch p.IssuedBy
                                    left join fetch p.Region

                                    left join fetch p.LegalDescList legal
                                where p.Status = true and p.Region.Id = :region
```

Generated SQL from HQL:

```
                            select count(legaldescl3_.entity_id) as col_0_0_ 
                                from Other_Rplans otherrplan0_ 
                                where otherrplan0_.status=1 and otherrplan0_.region_id=@p0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the error:

The use of 'fetch' keyword in the query causes this behavior. I know it doesn't make sense to use 'fetch' in count() but when building queries dynamically you try to re-use as much code (that should be the same in both queries) as possible for ease of maintenance and consistency.